# Add function at runtime depending on config

Tags: scala

Below code prints 4 statements in succession and then pauses for 1 second between subsequent 4 statements using a function and custom version of `println` :

```
object GoSlow extends App{


  println("step 1")  
  println("step 2") 
  println("step 3") 
  println("step 4")

  def f : Unit = Thread.sleep(1000)

  customPrintln("step 1 with function" , f)
  customPrintln("step 2 with function" , f)
  customPrintln("step 3 with function" , f)
  customPrintln("step 4 with function" , f)

  def customPrintln(x : Any , f : Unit) = {
    println(x) 
    f
  }


}
```

Instead of having a custom println function is it possible to inject a Thread.sleep at specified positions in the code (without using reflection) ? Or a pattern to slow down execution of particular areas of code ? I'm attempting to pause execution of code at particular times. But for most part the Thread.sleeps should be hidden.
Can traits be utilised to implement this behavior ?

Comment: And why not simply debugging? I mean, what is the exact use case of doing that?

Comment: @kaktusito use case is cause specific areas of code to run reduced speed, for debugging purposes. But do not want code littered with debug statements